# How is a "Gadol" recognized as such?

Tags: rabbis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gedole HaDor: who and how](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13000/gedole-hador-who-and-how)

The phrase "[Gedolim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadol)" or "Gadol haDor" has appeared in several questions and answers on this site (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17925/880), [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35837/who-today-are-the-most-eminent-jewish-religious-leaders-in-america), [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/32135/why-are-there-so-few-great-gedolim-today), and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13753/accurate-list-of-gedolim)).  However, the definition of "Gadol" is unclear.  <sub>(Most of these questions have been closed due to this  exact issue.)</sub>

- How does a rabbi become a "Gadol?"

  - Who decides?
  - Are there any specific requirements?

Comment: Did you edit in that possible duplicate yourself manually? Why?

Comment: I believe Rav Moshe answered this http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5553/reb-moshe-feinstein-in-the-new-york-times